# How to work with jQuery UI auto-complete extender for text searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm working with jQuery UI Auto Complete extenders for populating list. 
Here i include this [article](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/03/jquery-ui-autocomplete-textbox-with.html) for more reference of my code detail.

Here I modify method for auto complete. In article this calls from css class and I want from the ID of the control.

This is my jQuery script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           SearchText();
       });
       function SearchText() {
           $("#<%=txt_reason.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
               source: function (request, response) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       url: "Raise_Ticket.aspx/SearchReasons",
                       data: "{'prefixText':'" + $("#<%=txt_reason.ClientID %>").val() + "'}",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (data) {
                           response(data.d);
                       },
                       error: function (result) {
                           alert("Error");
                       }
                   });
               }
           });
       }
</script>
```

And this is my method:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> SearchReasons(string prefixText)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var query = db.Reasons.Where(r => r.ReasonText.Contains(prefixText)).Select(r => r).ToList();
        List<string> reasons = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            reasons.Add(item.ReasonText.ToString());
        }
        return reasons;
    }
}
```

The problem is not detecting this textbox not displaying result.

Comment: Can you provide your html markup? Any errors in the console?

Comment: i have got solution and now auto complete extender working.

Comment: i have small problem when user select something out of search result or move cursor to them then list disappears.

Comment: Please provide a demo of the issue on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           SearchText();
       });
       function SearchText() {
           $("#txt_reason").autocomplete({
               source: function (request, response) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       url: "Raise_Ticket.aspx/SearchReasons",
                       data: "{'prefixText':'" + $("#txt_reason").val() + "'}",
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (data) {
                           response(data.d);
                       },
                       error: function (result) {
                           alert("Error");
                       }
                   });
               }
           });
       }
</script>
```

Using this you can also try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#textbox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "URL",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },

                    success: function (retrieveddata) {
                        if (retrieveddata.length > 0) {
                    }
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        console.log("Error! " + request.responseText);
                    }
                })
            },
        });
 })
```

Take Tern Variable in Code

Comment: it's fine. but i provide user from select item from list. when i moves cursor resulted list then it's dissappear.

Comment: it's depend on your jquery that you are using else it will give you the result until you click on other area of the page

Comment: just look at http://jsfiddle.net/vFWUt/226/ what is it is there work in this scenario.

Comment: try to remove this contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: what u'r trying to do it's generates more trouble for me. hurry up with better solution.

Comment: it will work directly without giving id of the textbox try this

Comment: it's give me error like : POST http://localhost:6598/CRM/Staff/URL 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54210/discussion-between-shal-and-alpesh).

Comment: I think you need to handle spaces in that

Comment: i update my jquery-ui.js file with http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default now it's working like a charm..